# Real VNC won't connect to OS X Leopard VNC server

Tags: windows, macos, vnc

I have 3 machines.  2 Macs, 1 Dell.
1 of the Macs is running as a VNC server and the other Mac connects great with Chicken of the VNC.
Sadly, this app does not exist for Windows so I'm using RealVNC to view from Windows.
I connect the exact same way as with the Mac, but on Windows when it connects, I see a program pop up and then immediately close.
I have tried all options available on RealVNC and nothing changes things.  Anyone have any idea what I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try UltraVNC or TightVNC on the client and see if that resolves your problem.  I've experienced a few issues with RealVNC not being completely compatible with Mac VNC servers on a few occasions.

UltraVNC (free and open source)
  http://www.ultravnc.org/

TightVNC (free and open source)
  http://www.tightvnc.org/